# Address columns in dataframe by numbers

Tags: r

have a dataframe with 3 columns (y & 2 predictors). can address columns e.g. with `height$df1` or `df1[,2]`. Same result. Both are vectors (`is.vector`). In  some cases in conbination with formulas like `confint` the output is different.

this code deliver the correct results:

```
confint(lm(df1[,1] ~ height, data=df1), "height")
```

this one is not working, it ends up with `NA` values:

```
confint(lm(earning ~ df1[, 2], data=df1), "height")
```

Would like to address the dataframe with columnnumbers, like `df1[, 2]`. What is the correct approach?
Thanks vor any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a formula with `paste` and it should work

```
confint(lm(paste0('earning ~ ', names(df1)[2]), data = df1), "height")
```

Using a small reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ mtcars[,6], data = mtcars)
confint(fit, 'wt')
#   2.5 % 97.5 %
#wt    NA     NA
fit <- lm(paste0('mpg ~', names(mtcars)[6]), data = mtcars)
confint(fit, 'wt')
#       2.5 %    97.5 %
#wt -6.486308 -4.202635
```

Comment: it works. And how have to do it with mpg, resp. earning too?

Comment: to address all vectors by numbers... in my example "earning" as well. something like: `confint(lm(names(df1)[1] ~ names(df1)[2], data = df1), "height")` Thanks.

Comment: @Eli3 Just do `confint(lm(paste0(names(df1)[1], " ~ ", names(df1)[2]), data = df1), "height")`

Comment: #akrun: Thank you it works. Can you please explain why it works like this and not with my attempt df1[, 2]?

Comment: @Eli3 In your attempt, the attributes created in terms are `df1[, 2]` instead of the column name and thus it wouldn't match with the column name

Comment: @Eli3 just to understand where it is causing issue, check the `str(fit)` elements in both cases, you would see some attributes have names as `df1[,2]` instead of the 'height' and this causes the matching issue, when. you provide `confint` with 'height'

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reformulate` to create the formula :

```
confint(lm(reformulate(names(df1)[2], "earning"), df1), 'height')
```

Using `mtcars` as an example :

```
confint(lm(reformulate(names(mtcars)[6], "mpg"), mtcars), 'wt')

#       2.5 %    97.5 %
#wt -6.486308 -4.202635
```

Comment: and how to do it with more variables, like: mpg ~ wt + hp ?

Comment: @Eli3 `confint(lm(reformulate(names(mtcars)[c(4, 6)], "mpg"), mtcars), 'wt')` like this.